# How to get apt after I accidentally uninstalled it

Tags: apt, dpkg

Is it possible to use dpkg to install apt? It was uninstalled accidentally. If not, how can I get apt without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Edit: The following is what I get when I try to install apt with dpkg...

```
root@ben-HP-ENVY-dv4-Notebook-PC:/home/ben/Downloads# sudo dpkg -i apt.deb(Reading 

database ... 285851 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace apt 0.9.7.9+deb7u1 (using apt.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement apt ...
Setting up apt (0.9.7.9+deb7u1) ...
gpg: key B98321F9: "Squeeze Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 473041FA: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 65FFB764: "Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 46925553: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg:              unchanged: 4
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

Comment: How did you "accidentally" uninstall `apt`? Did you delete it or did you actually "uninstall" it? If it's just been deleted, you should be able to copy it from another machine.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think I uninstalled a program that required it, and I typed yes without seeing the list of programs it will also uninstall it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If I have to reinstall ubuntu, it's no problem. I was just curious if I could avoid it

Comment: I re-iterate, what **command** did you use? `apt-get remove`?

Comment: Its possible via Aptitude and live CD.

Comment: I believe I did @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @Speedysnail6 Right. Well `apt-get remove` doesn't remove dependencies. [Here](http://linuxwave.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-extract-deb-file-without-having.html) is one method to extract files from a `deb` without the tool. But, I'd probably just reinstall - because it will take a very long time to manually repair that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was actually following a tutorial for some program and the terminal made me type "Yes, I understand the risks!" but I shoud've looked :P. I'll reinstall

Comment: check this solutions with using wget to download the deb package  --http://askubuntu.com/questions/295171/how-to-install-apt-get-package-manager --- after you download the deb package its just a simple click to install

Comment: "Preparing to replace apt 0.9.7.9+deb7u1 (using apt.deb)" this tells me that you  had installed apt-get. Could you run `apt-cache policy apt` and `type apt-get`.

Comment: I'll try this my laptop is being repaired right now. So I'll do it when I get it back...

Answer (score 1):

Yes I did it. I got into the same problem when I tried to install oracle-java7-installer with

```
sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer
```

It told me that I'm going to do a very harmful thing (Remember I'm running trusty unstable development release) but I said 'Yes do as I sak' and it started removing everything including itself 'apt' so I forced stopped it. Coming back to the question, just download apt from

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/apt/download

replace trusty with your release name and then run

```
sudo dpkg --install apt_0.9.15.4ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

and that's it. It worked for at least.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to find a deb package for it, and use `dpkg -i <package>` or for aptitude.

Try to install the source code, as it was already installed, should resolve dependencies and inside de folder run:

```
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/apt

Comment: Thanks for your help. In what directory do I do those commands because there are dependency errors when I tried to install it using the link you gave me and dpkg.

Comment: This is what happens http://gyazo.com/e0c901e85d02ed372597ae6d573a0fd1

Comment: Don't suggest installing from Debian sources.