# Ubuntu 18.04 apt: command not found

Tags: apt, server, 18.04

I have a problem in my ubuntu, I did sudo apt update, it zupdated me but since then I can't use the apt command to download things from the repository I have a question if there is any option to download the apt package ... .deb for this Bionic Beaver operating system or do you have to do an os reinstall. I already checked in /usr/bin/ there is no such directory as apt and apt-get the only directory is /etc/apt.

I still used dpkg to check, and more specifically
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apt spit out this "/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: apt is broken or not fully installed" I checked with the sudo dpkg -l | grep apt command where it displays the package to me, specifically |rc apt 1.6.17 amd64|, another thing is that my /usr/bin/apt folder disappeared

Comment: What is the output for `which apt`? By any chance, did you manually update python?

Comment: You can re-install the apt package using dpkg - see for example [How to get apt back after uninstalling it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830070/how-to-get-apt-back-after-uninstalling-it). Make sure to download the correct version for your OS.

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in 2018-April (why it's 18.04 with the *year.month* format used) which had 5 years of *standard* supported life..  Run `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm your status, and you'll note EOSS has occurred. Some architectures will continue to get upgrades during May 2023 due to a Canonical decision to extend life (*by one month*), but your system is effectively EOSS now & you should plan your upgraded asap.  EOSS for all 18.04 is 31-May-2023.

Comment: `apt update` updates the package database, it does not install any software packages. You probably also ran `apt upgrade`. If you have an amd64 system, the `apt` package version should be 1.6.1. Download e.g. http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt-utils_1.6.1_amd64.deb

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi does not return anything

Comment: @Bodo It is actually possible that this is the cause because I also did the upgrade, actually there is this version 1.6.17 more precisely it displays to me like this 
rc apt 1.6.17 amd64 commandline package manager, so I have to reinstall apt from scratch ?

Comment: Difficult to guess without knowing what exactly you did and what happened. Normally, the upgrade should not remove the file `/usr/bin/apt` unless something failed. 
Please [edit] your question and add all details to the question. Always show the command and its output. Did you add any non-standard package sources?

Comment: I would suggest you to perform a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. You can backup your files from the live USB.

Comment: Well I still used sudo dpkg-reconfigure apt to check and it actually spit out something like this /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: apt is broken or not fully installed I think it's possible that reinstalling can only help me in this case unfortunately but I'll keep looking, @Bodo I'll just edit the thread about the stuff I used under verification

Comment: Installing `apt` manually might fix the problem if it's the only one and if you find the correct package version for your old Ubuntu version. Since upgrading your distribution to 20.04 LTS and then 22.04 LTS needs two steps, it might be easier to backup your data and do a fresh installation of a current 22.04 LTS.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support